# crear una variable de tipo clase

Tags: java

Lo siento si mi pregunta esta mal formulada ,pero tengo la siguiente duda ,recien estoy aprendiendo java y yo que sepa los tipos de variable son `int` `double` `String` ,etc.. pero  me he dado cuenta que se puede crear una variale de tipo 'nombre de la clase' , quisiera saber que tipo de dato almacena eso , es este caso 'casa'

```
package ejemplo;

public class casa {

**casa** tamaño;
}
```

Comment: Te refieres a crear un objeto de "X" clase?, si es eso puedes crearla de la siguiente forma Casa casa = new Casa();  sobre que almacenaría, en este caso si encapsulas sus atributos(casa,tamanio), podrás acceder a ellos, recordar que para dar un nombre a cualquier variable no puedes usar "ñ" o acentuar las letras.

Comment: Tenía la misma duda cuando empecé a estudar sobre nodos, en listas. Y lo comprendí cuando vi el video " Variables de Instancia, de Clase y locales" por Turbo Código; youtube. En dicho video se explica muy bien; espero que lo observe.

Comment: @5frags Si bien no es completo, Java da soporte a gran parte de los _code points_ de Unicode, por lo que sí se puede usar tildes y eñes para nombrar variables. Muchos desarrolladores no lo recomiendan porque el soporte no es completo al 100%, y por tradición heredada de lenguajes más antiguos donde sí es ilegal utilizar dichos caracteres en identificadores de variable. Pero si de todas formas no quieres usar eñes, antes que llamar _tamanio_ a una variable, cosa que me parece horrible, yo usaría sinónimos, o la llamaría _size_, lo que me llevaría a programar nombrando en inglés.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como mencionas existen los tipos `int`, `double`, `string`, pero en el caso de `Casa` es algo más complejo.

Para responder tu pregunta, lo mejor es aclarar varias cosas:

Primero estás definiendo una clase `Casa`. Esta clase puede contener los tipos `int`, `double`, `string`, para definir diferentes atributos, por ejemplo así:

```
public class Casa{
    string color;
    int cantidad_de_cuartos;
    bool tiene_garaje;
}
```

Luego, ésta clase como tal puede ser utilizada como una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
Casa miCasa = new Casa();

miCasa.color = "verde";
miCasa.cantidad_de_cuartos = 3;
miCasa.tiene_garaje = true;
```

En este ejemplo mi variable `miCasa` es de tipo `Casa`, pero interactúo con sus atributos que son de tipo `int`, `double`, `string`. A esto se le llama un Objeto.

Además, mi objeto de casa podría ser aún más complejo, puede tener otros objetos dentro, métodos y demás cosas que necesite, pero si lo explico aquí se sale de lo que preguntas. :)

Entonces volviendo a tu pregunta **que tipo de dato almacena eso?**, almacena lo que tu quieras, la clase la "configuras" como quieres y estableces lo que tendrá, no tiene un tipo de dato específico como tal.

Comment: gracias , ya lo entendi

Answer (score 0):

Las variables de clase son variables cuyos valores son los mismos para la clase y para todas sus instancias.

Para indicar que una variable es una variable de clase se utiliza la palabra clave static en la declaración de la variables:

```
static tipoVariable nombreVariable;
```

Cómo podras darte cuenta el tipado es el mismo, la diferencia radica en que al usar variables de clase estas estaran presentes desde que se crea el objeto y no cuando hace una instancia del objeto.

Puede que te ayude este link

http://profesores.fi-b.unam.mx/carlos/java/java_basico4_4.html

Comment: a tamaño le puedo dar valores enteros ,texto ?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que te refieres es como declarar una variable tipo clase, en lo que entendí pongo este ejemplo.

```
public class casa {

   int tamaño;
}

public class miscasas {

    casa micasa1;
    casa micasa2;

 public miscasas(){
 micasa1 = new casa();
 micasa2 = new casa();
 micasa1.tamaño = 30;
 micasa2.tamaño = 50;
}
    }
```

en este ejemplo tenemos la clase casa con el atributo tamaño tipo entero y la clase miscasas con los atributos, micasa1 y micasa2 ambos tipo casa, ambos objetos por ser tipo casa tienen el atributo tamaño y les asigne un tamaño a cada uno, son el mismo tipo de objeto pero los atributos con diferentes valores.

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de datos son conocidos cómo **TDA (tipos de datos abstractos)**
Son datos que siempre están compuestos de datos primitivos o incluso de datos de tipo Objeto y que el programador crea para satisfacer sus necesidades.

Por ejemplo alguien puede hacer una casa con los siguientes valores:

```
public class Casa{
int largo;
int ancho;

public Casa(int largo, int ancho) {
this.largo=largo;
this.ancho=ancho;
} 
}
```

Pero a otro programador le pueden interesar otros datos de una casa:

```
    public class Casa {
    String color;
    Persona habitantes[];

    public Casa(String color, Persona habitantes[]) {
    this.color=color;
    this.habitantes=habitantes;
    } 

}
```

En el primer caso la casa solamente se compone de tipos de datos primitivos, mientras que en el segundo caso la casa está compuesta de datos de tipo Objeto.

Comment: Pese a que tu respuesta va por buen camino, matizaría que un TAD se corresponde más con el concepto de interfaz que con el de clase, porque un TAD es la definición abstracta de un tipo de datos, sin entrar en detalles de implementación. Una clase sería la implementación concreta de un TAD. Como la interfaz List, que define un TAD (lista de elementos), que se implementa en varias clases, como LinkedList (lista enlazada) y ArrayList (lista basada en vector).