# Tipo que tiene el nombre de la clase

Tags: java

Me he encontrado con la siguiente clase Java:

```
public class MiClase {
    int informacion;
    MiClase siguiente;

    public MiClase(int valor) {
        informacion = valor;
        siguiente = null;
    }
}
```

Existen tipos nativos en Java como int y String. Pero en esta clase que me encontré, el autor está creando un nuevo tipo: **MiClase**, que es el nombre de la clase.

1. ¿Al crear una clase, automáticamente se crea un tipo de dato que lleva el
   nombre de esa clase? ¿Cómo se llama esto?
2. ¿Qué tipo de información puede guardar la variable *siguiente*: int, bool, String?

En [este lugar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64356/crear-una-variable-de-tipo-clase) preguntan lo mismo que yo, pero en las respuestas que dan, hablan de instanciar objeto, y eso no es a lo que se refiere la pregunta.

¿Me ayudan por favor a entender esto? Por favor, soy nuevo en Java, así que agradecería absolutamente si pudieran contestar de modo que pueda entender.

**Reformulo la pregunta (pero dejando la 1ra formulación para ver los cambios)**

La clase original es esta:

```
public class Nodo {
    int informacion;
    Nodo siguiente;

    public Nodo(int valor) {
        informacion = valor;
        siguiente = null;
    }
}
```

Alrededor del minuto 9:00 de [este video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsBxpVkPpYg&index=33&list=PLyvsggKtwbLXEZjb8HrNTbWesTKIfpNak) es de donde saqué la clase, y ahí se ve cómo se trabajan las listas tipo pila. Ahora que reviso nuevamente el video, el autor no se refiere a *siguiente* como a una variable, sino como un objeto.

Esto cambia totalmente la duda y la pregunta. Porque entiendo que normalmente los objetos se crean así: *Nodo siguiente = new Nodo();* Pero en el video resulta que un objeto se puede crear igual que como se declara una variable: *Nodo siguiente;* Pero entonces ya no entiendo nada, porque se supone que la clase Nodo tiene 2 atributos: *informacion* y *siguiente*. Pero ¿cómo uno de sus atributos puede ser un objeto instanciado de la misma clase?

Por favor, discúlpenme por plantear mis dudas de modo incorrecto, general e incluso superficial. Pero he buscado intentando encontrar respuestas, y aún no he tenido éxito. Por eso me he obligado a solicitar su ayuda para que me echen un poco de luz. Gracias.

Comment: Todo esté tema es sobre programación orientado a objetos, y de hecho es básico. Mi sugerencia sería que no trates de entenderlo solo con ver el código porque este tema te va servir de ahora en adelante como desarrollador, trata de leer y entender desde lo más básico sobre POO, hay muchos ejemplosde clases y atributos(tan trillados como casa, auto, persona, familia, etc) que te van a ayudar a entender todo. Otra cosa es que el enlace que pones en la pregunta ya tiene una respuesta válida y es muy fácil de entender. Finalmente, edita tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida. Puedes ir a [ask]

Comment: cierto es que ya tiene una respuesta aceptada la otra pregunta, pero el tema de poner `MiClase siguiente` al menos no lo veo yo tampoco explicado @VíctorHugoTirado entonces si tienes un aporte que hacerle al OP considero deberías ponerlo, por que `MiClase(){}` abajo es un método constructor, pero en la línea de arriba no es claro para quien pregunta

Comment: Estoy evitando responder la pregunta debido a que es bastante amplia, por eso la sugerencia de edición. También estoy evitando, para más entendimiento, la parte de "MiClase siguiente" ya que esa parte del código sugiere la estructura de una lista simple, y ese tema es un poco más avanzado para alguien que recién está empezando con POO en java. Solo se le brinda la información suficiente sin intención de responder dentro de un comentario.

Comment: no deberías estar evitándolo @VíctorHugoTirado pues para eso esta esta comunidad para apoyar a resolver dudas, la facilidad  con la que el OP comprenda tu respuesta dependerá mucho de tu capacidad para explicarlo, pues si lo evitas el sigue sin saberlo

Comment: Lo hice mas que todo por el motivo de la pregunta amplia, con respecto a la estructura de listas simples son un tema que comprende la POO pero es mas avanzado, y si lo respondo seria igual de amplia que la pregunta. Seria yo es que este promoviendo este tipo de preguntas. Para no extenderlo(y se toma muy bien la sugerencia de respuesta para poder brindarle algo de ayuda :)  )  le dejo este enlace para entender la estructura que explica las listas simples, obviamente para complementar el enlace que se publicó junto con la pregunta.  (https://diariodebian.wordpress.com/tag/listas-simples-java/)

Comment: Gracias a todos por responder. Acabo de reformular la pregunta- @VíctorHugoTirado, no sé cómo lo entreviste, pero efectivamente la clase la obtuve de un ejemplo relacionado con listas tipo pila.

Answer (score 2):

1. ¿Al crear una clase, automáticamente se crea un tipo de dato que lleva el nombre de esa clase?

   - Podría decirse que **sí**, las clases son un tipo de dato abstracto(ADT) si se utilizan para guardar información( se pueden crear clases con puro métodos y en ese caso no, al respecto investiga sobre las *Utility Class* o clases de métodos de utilería en los que se previene que se creen instancias con constructores privados y otros trucos similares ).
2. ¿Cómo se llama esto?

   - Clase, una instancia u objeto creado es del tipo de la clase que lo define que tiene el molde para crear nuevos objetos. No sé si exista el concepto pero me atrevería a llamarle definición recursiva ya que el objeto se define en términos de sí mismo.<sup>1</sup>
3. ¿Qué tipo de información puede guardar la variable siguiente: int, bool, String?

   - información de la clase(o del tipo) `MiClase`

Para ayudarte a entender más el programa que incluyes te pondré algo de código sobre como usar el código que compartiste.

```
public class MiClase {
    int informacion;
    MiClase siguiente;

    public MiClase(int valor) {
        informacion = valor;
        siguiente = null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      MiClase miClase = new MiClase(1);
      System.out.println(miClase.informacion);
      miClase.informacion=0;
      System.out.println(miClase.informacion);
      miClase.siguiente = new MiClase(1);
      System.out.println(miClase.siguiente.informacion);
   }
}
```

La salida de tu programa debería de ser:

> 1
>
> 0
>
> 1

Explicación del programa:

Primero, como sabrás en la mayoría de los lenguajes imperativos hay una pila de ejecución, donde se almacenan los procesos a correr, de esa manera al ejecutarse un subprocedimiento se regresará a la dirección siguiente de donde se haya quedado la ejecución.

Debido a que definimos nuestra clase en *modo híbrido*( objeto con método main ), el programa de ejemplo tiene dos frames en el stack o dos secciones independientes, la primera es nuestro main, y la segunda es nuestro constructor.

Usando este conocimiento la ejecución se realiza visualmente de la siguiente manera<sup>2</sup>:

[image: visualización de la ejecución basado en stack e instancias de objetos]

Ahora que si necesitas un análisis más profundo, el objeto `args` que es de la clase String[] o dicho de otra forma de tipo arreglo de cadenas se crea al inicio pero nunca se usa. El método `main` primero procesa args y posteriormente comienza a crear instancias o ejemplares del tipo `MiClase` y asocia un objeto con otro mediante el puntero llamado siguiente. Aquí la visualización<sup>3</sup>:

[image: jelliot visualización]

Como observarás en la línea 12 la modificación de los valores de un objeto desde fuera del él puede resultar un poco confusa, por ello te recomiendo que encapsules apropiadamente tu clase de la siguiente forma:

[image: UML de la clase pero bien encapsulada]

### Notas

<sup>1</sup> Un ejemplo de definición recursiva en el contexto semántico del lenguaje natural como se usa en el ámbito computacional es GNU, que significa "GNU No es Unix", es decir, GNU se define únicamente en términos de sí mismo, me atrevería a aseverar que actualmente solo un humano podría entenderlo sin quedarse pensando el resto de la eternidad en que GNU nunca ha sido definido por completo en la definición recursiva que implica su nombre.

<sup>2</sup> Visualización creada con [cscircles](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/)

<sup>3</sup> Visualización creada con Jeliot 3.7.2 (debes agregar el import `import jeliot.io.*;` al inicio para la demo interactiva)